# Getting a result of current running job of a project java code snippet

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

I want to get the current running build status of a particular job in Java for my plugin.

Comment: have you put some efforts ?

Comment: do you mean that you want to check if the job is running or not? (if not what do you mean by status of current running build)